# High traffic between mongos and mongo config server

Tags: mongodb, high-traffic

Recently we noticed a huge outgoing traffic from mongodb config server to mongos servers: 750GB per day. We use mongodb sharded cluster with 2 shards and 3 config servers. Mongo db stats:

```
mongos> db.stats()
{
    "raw" : {
        "shard1/shard1a:27017,shard1b:27017" : {
            "db" : "ecquant",
            "collections" : 4,
            "objects" : 539175,
            "avgObjSize" : 158073.44626883665,
            "dataSize" : 85229250392,
            "storageSize" : 86339362224,
            "numExtents" : 73,
            "indexes" : 3,
            "indexSize" : 43185632,
            "fileSize" : 90084212736,
            "nsSizeMB" : 16,
            "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 5
            },
            "ok" : 1
        },
        "shard2/shard2a:27017,shard2b:27017" : {
            "db" : "ecquant",
            "collections" : 3,
            "objects" : 327497,
            "avgObjSize" : 257366.1745054153,
            "dataSize" : 84286650052,
            "storageSize" : 85961473456,
            "numExtents" : 61,
            "indexes" : 2,
            "indexSize" : 31632944,
            "fileSize" : 90084212736,
            "nsSizeMB" : 16,
            "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 5
            },
            "ok" : 1
        }
    },
    "objects" : 866672,
    "avgObjSize" : 195593.72251209224,
    "dataSize" : 169515900444,
    "storageSize" : 172300835680,
    "numExtents" : 134,
    "indexes" : 5,
    "indexSize" : 74818576,
    "fileSize" : 180168425472,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

MongoDB version: 2.4.10

MongoDB manual doesn't say anything about high traffic from mongo config server. Does anyone have an idea what can cause it?

Comment: I haven't heard any such pattern. Do you see anything specific in config db log files or mongos log files that may indicate some activity? What is your config db size? How did the traffic change stop?

Comment: We've got this pattern and are working up a detailed email for the mongo list...